# MS Access 2007 - Property for text box to allow end-user to hit enter for return, not next

Tags: ms-access, controls, textbox, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a form that is used for data entry, and on one form there is a text box that is used to enter notes. However, if the user hits `<ENTER>` I need the cursor to stay in that text box and start a new line, but currently it is jumping to the next control (text box).

Is there a simple property setting that would do the trick? Or a VBA method that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ac2003, there is the "Enter Key Behaviour" property, which gets set to "New Line in Field".

Answer (score 2):

I suspect Scott's answer is what you're looking for.  That property is available in Access 2007 also.

Another option would be to have the users enter CTRL+Enter to insert a line into the text control.  Your users may not go for it, though.

Comment: @Hans ....guessing they don't because I didn't know that, and they were asking me about changing it. pretty cool thanks!

Comment: is this called "Carriage return"?

Comment: @Justin Maybe.  I'd have to test to figure out what gets inserted: carriage return; linefeed; or carriage return + linefeed.  Or you could test it.  :-)

Comment: i just meant is that the proper terminology for that idea?